# Gradle 6.3 Docker Palantir Plugin: No signature of method: build_8uxeoxw0v35xxabibl49jhru8.docker()

Tags: docker, gradle, groovy

Below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id("com.palantir.docker") version "0.25.0"
    id("com.palantir.docker-run") version "0.25.0"
}


apply plugin:"com.palantir.docker"

docker { //line 50
    name = "dev/${project.name}:${version}" 
    tag("name", "dev/${project.name}:${version}")
    buildArgs(["name", "${project.name}"])
    copySpec.from("build").into("build")
    pull(true)
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
}

dockerRun {
    name = "${project.name}"
    image = "dev/${project.name}:".plus(version)
    ports("8080:8080")
}
```

AM getting the below error during the gradle build

```
Build file 'build.gradle' line: 50

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'currency-conversion-service'.
> No signature of method: build_8uxeoxw0v35xxabibl49jhru8.docker() is applicable for argument types: (build_8uxeoxw0v35xxabibl49jhru8$_run_closure5) values: [build_8uxeoxw0v35xxabibl49jhru8$_run_closure5@249d76b5]
```

is this a bug? or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> is this a bug? or am I doing anything wrong?

The latter :P

The annoying thing about Groovy closures in the Gradle DSL is that when you reference something that doesn't exist, it does not always show the exact location of the error.

For instance, everything in the `{}` block for the `docker` method could in theory be correct, depending on what context it is executed in. However, when you run it, Groovy says the block isn't valid for the `docker` method, but doesn't tell you why.

I found that the best way to find the offending line is to just start commenting them out one-by-one until compilation succeeds (though it might fail on other things, which is fine).

In your case, you are passing an array to `buildArgs` where it really should be a map. To fix it, change it to `buildArgs(["name": "${project.name}"])` (notice the colon instead of the comma).